# MySQL installation to a different drive

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to install MySQL 5.6.1 community edition on a different drive instead of C:\ drive which is default drive for machine, but I am not getting any option in the installer to change the path. So I had to rely on the default drive.

After installation to the C: drive, then I wanted to changed the data path to the D: drive.

I googled and tried various ways by changing the data path, but after changing data path, the MySQL service doesn't start. I tried to change access permission on new data path, but it is still same error.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried the following steps on [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008):

- Navigate to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.4\` and locate the *my.ini* file
- Find the SERVER SECTION and go to approx line 76 and
  modify the datadir line to where you want your MySQL application data to be stored
- Now navigate to `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.4\data\` and copy and paste the *mysql* folder into your new location.
- Restart the MySQL
  Server in *Control Panel* → *Administrative Tools* → *Service*

Comment: Look in the MySQL error log - that should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I checked into Win2008.err file and found below lines:            2014-02-02 22:25:41 2564 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2014-02-02 22:25:41 2564 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2014-02-02 22:25:41 2564 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2014-02-02 22:25:43 2564 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 1 remaining clients
2014-02-02 22:25:43 2564 [Warning] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3  user: 'root'