# Installing MySQL on the D: drive instead of C:

Tags: mysql, sql, windows-10

I would like to install MySQL in the D: drive instead of my C: drive and subsequently have all my databases stored in a folder that should look like this `D:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server %VERSION%`

I wasn't able to find satisfactory answers:

- *[Install MySQL in D drive](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,644290,644290)*
- *[Install MySQL in D drive](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,39720)*
- *[MySQL installation to a different drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510085/mysql-installation-to-different-drive)*

And in the MySQL documentation section, the only mini-guide is this:

- *[Chapter 3 Setting Alternative Server Paths with MySQL Installer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-change-path-proc.html)*

Is it feasible to install MySQL in D: without incurring in major or even minor problems down the road? How can I conduct the installation to avoid possible pains in the future?

Comment: This kind of questions are generally offtopic on stackoverflow.. But no it should not matter, MySQL should be designed to run correctly a other disk stations should not matter if you run it on C:, D:, E: ....  or Z: for that matter.. Well if your C: is a SSD disk and your D: is a 7200 rpm HDD disk the worse which can happen is worse performance it should not give errors so be aware off that but still you can change the configuration to write tables on the SSD disk..

Comment: The answer for this question is added [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-change-path-proc.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the latest version of MySQL Installer, the "Advanced Options" link as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-change-path-proc.html) is no longer there. However, you can trick the installer into giving you extra options where you can change the Install Directory and the Data Directory.

If you are installing MySQL Server 8.0.22, for example, the installer will try to create the folder **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0**. But if you create this folder before opening the installer, then when you go to step 2 in the installer, you will be presented with "Path Conflicts" options where you can specify different directories.

[Click here to see a screenshot of the secret Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KSdQ.png)

---

**Note**: This same approach works for MySQL Workbench. The folder you would create is **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE**.

Answer (score 13):

In the 8.0.26 (installer version 1.4), you can choose the Custom Setup type.

[image: Custom Setup]

And in the next step, you go to Advanced Options and specify the location to install.

[image: select each item from the Product To Be Installed list]

**NOTE:** Select each item first, then Advanced Options will be visible.

[image: Click on the Advanced Options]

Comment: this must be the accepted answer

Comment: Just to clarify this answer, you have to click on each line in the Products To Be Installed box first to get the Advanced Options link to show for that product.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's like they tried to hide it...